# Get logged on user on external Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, web-parts

Lots of places use sharepoint.

How can we securely retrieve the logged on sharepoint user when they view our app inside a web part?

Comment: Is your app running *in* SharePoint, or are you viewing through an IFrame/Page Viewer?

Comment: Sorry, should say through a Page Viewer/iFrame

Unless there is another way to run an external hosted app actually in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

If your WebPart is running in SharePoint you can get the current user from the SPContext.

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName
```

Shane.

Comment: Thanks, but if the web part is external, ie Sharepoint is on the local network intranet, and our app is hosted elsewhere, we can't do that.

Comment: Ah ok, could you create a webpart that renders an iFrame and perhaps appends an extra value to the querystring containing the information you need?

Comment: Thats possible but unsecure. ie http://ourapp.com?user=SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName

Anyone could just tamper with the URL

Comment: If you can't use the HttpContext, then this is the only technique I could think of - could you encrypt the value before you append it to your querystring?

Answer (score 0):

you need to be in the SharePoint context in order to get the SPUser object in code. 
Otherwise you could just try

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

But of course this will not the the AD name and not the SharePoint user.

Comment: That wouldnt work though as its just an external app in an iframe inside sharepoint

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean - you can only get the HttpContext, not the SPContext.

Comment: Agreed, you should be able to get the AD credentials from the HttpContext